# How to track who invited a bot with discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

How to track who invited a Discord bot in a guild, using discord.js? I want to create an anti-bot event and take action against the inviter.

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How Do i Check Who Invited Who Discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67740249/how-do-i-check-who-invited-who-discord-js)

Comment: However that tracks normal users. It's not a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Using audit logs will suffice (you will need to give the bot perms). Using [`GuildAuditLogsEntry.executor`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildAuditLogsEntry?scrollTo=executor) and [`GuildAuditLogsEntry.target`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildAuditLogsEntry?scrollTo=target). Here is an implementation (it will check if the member is a bot and if they are, do something of your choice)

```js
client.on("guildMemberAdd", async (member) => {
  if (!member.user.bot) return;
  const auditLogs = await member.guild.fetchAuditLogs({type: "BOT_ADD"})
  const auditLog = auditLogs.entries.first()
  //you can take ban with "auditLog.executor.ban()"
  //you can also ban the bot with "auditLog.target.ban"
})
```

<sup>Tested on discord.js v13</sup>